# Create a widevine license proxy server using NodeJS

Tags: networking, axios, drm, widevine, shaka

I am using Shaka Player for media streaming dash DRM-protected content on our site. I want to create a proxy server between the client and the original license request so that all the license requests get forwarded to my server and it requests the license and forwards the response back to the client.

Code:
I have an express server running that takes `contentId` as a parameter. I create a `POST` request using axios. For the request `body` & `headers` I just pass from the original request.

As the player makes two requests, my first request which contains the `2-Byte` Payload
gets accepted and I get the desired response as shown here.
[image: Image 1: Body payload of first Request]

[image: Image 2: Response of first request]

The player gets the desired data and makes the 2nd request with the new payload but at this point my server throws the error as the Request from server gets failed `403: Access Denied`.

[image: Image 3: Payload of second request]

Need help in knowing where my code is failing. I also checked on SOF for more such questions and found no idea of doing but people saying that it's possible. Just to add, If the license URL's are directly added to player then it works.

Comment: Any solutions you have received?